# Laravel Tinker: Class 'Psy\Exception\ErrorException' not found

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, factory, tinker

I'm trying to run Laravel 5.5 tinker but get an exception when i try to run the factory Command. For example:

```
factory(App\Article::class, 100)->create();
```

When i try to run lets say the User:class command  in another repository it works without any problems.

```
   PHP error:  Class 'Psy\Exception\ErrorException' not found in /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Shell.php on line 812
```

**Extended Error-Message:**

```
PHP warning:  opendir(/Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/database/factories): failed to open dir: Too many open files in /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php on line 145
PHP Warning:  Uncaught Psy\Exception\ErrorException: PHP warning:  require(/Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/database/factories/ArticleFactory.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files in /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.php on line 202 in /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.php:202
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Shell.php(809): Psy\Exception\ErrorException::throwException(2, 'require(/Users/...', '/Users/sebastia...', 202)
#1 /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.php(202): Psy\Shell->handleError(2, 'require(/Users/...', '/Users/sebastia...', 202, Array)
#2 /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.php(202): require()
#3 /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/laravel/framework in /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.php on line 202
PHP Fatal error:  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::load(): Failed opening required '/Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/database/factories/ArticleFactory.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.php on line 202
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Psy\Exception\ErrorException: PHP warning:  include(/Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files in /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444 in /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Shell.php(809): Psy\Exception\ErrorException::throwException(2, 'include(/Users/...', '/Users/sebastia...', 444)
#1 /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): Psy\Shell->handleError(2, 'include(/Users/...', '/Users/sebastia...', 444, Array)
#2 /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#3 /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/Users/sebastia...')
#4 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Sym in /Users/sebastian/Development/app.manager/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
```

What I've alrdy tried:

- removing and re-ading the laravel/tinker from composer.json

Comment: Your stacktrace shows that you're getting "Too many open files" errors. If you fix that issue, I'm assuming the rest will follow.

Comment: Are you catching an `ErrorException` or `Exception` in your code? If you, you may need to add a slash before it: `\Exception `

Comment: @patricus Thank you for the answer. But what kind of files? Even after a restart from my computer and the webserver i got this error. So i'm wondering which files are open.

Comment: @aynber Thank you for your answer. Not it just played around with Laravel Tinker and added a Factory for my articles.

Comment: Your web server has to open up every single PHP file that is accessed. Most likely you will need to use the linux command `ulimit -n` to up the limit of files allowed to be open. You should be able to find more information by Googling for "php too many open files" to get some ideas.

Comment: Are you defining a state in your factory? I've had that cause this error